# 404 when using POST / GET parameters in WordPress 3.4

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters, http-post, get-request

I have permalinks set to "Post name".

If I put in my address bar: http://www.example.com/section1/whitepapers/, WordPress loads it correctly, but if I send a POST or GET request to the same URL, it throws a 404 error inside WordPress.

This is my htaccess file: https://gist.github.com/3062205

Could someone shed a light on what might be happening here?

**NOTE:** The 404 error is thrown by WordPress, it's not a Server 404 message.

Comment: are you using a custom page template on that url?
if not, try creating a page template assign to that page, in your template file before the get_header call, add this
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); echo "</pre>";
or add that to your template header file.

Comment: hi Marty, yes, I'm using a custom page template, I've tried that before but seems like the url is not even recognized, it redirects me to a 404 error page even though it's the same URL.

Answer (score 2):

What parameters do you submit with the GET and POST requests. Wordpress will strip out any parameters with 'name' in it. I my case i renamed a parameter 'firstname' to 'fn' and it worked. See [wordpress-404page-not-found-on-form-posted-data](http://www.lost-in-code.com/platforms/wordpress/wordpress-404page-not-found-on-form-posted-data/)

Answer (score 1):

could your url be redirecting from WWW to nonWWW or vice-versa?

Can you see the header response it returns

Comment: Hi fedmich! thanks for your fast response, I do have access to the header response and I made sure it's not redirecting from WWW to non WWW or viceversa.